# Is it possible to use nodejs style modules in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, typescript

In node, I can define a module like this by setting the properties of `exports` object :

**module.js**

```
exports.fun = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
};
```

and the ask for it using `var module = require('module')` in  and the use the `module.fun()` function.

Is it possible to define the module in TypeScript like this:

**module.ts**

```
exports.fun = function (val :string) {
    console.log(val);
};
```

and then import the module in some other file using node like syntax, say, `import module = require('module.ts')` so that it compiles to nodejs but, if now I use `module.fun()` in some `.ts` file, it should give me an error if the arguments don't match the type specified in module.ts file.

How can I do this in Typescript?

Comment: Typescript just compiles to JavaScript. It doesn't add any functionality like modules as it's not a library itself. You'd need to look into one of the AMD libraries to allow a similar syntax (https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)

Comment: Here is a video demo : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1&t=7m20s

Comment: @basarat I did come across that video. I am saying that in nodejs modules, I assign properties to the `exports` .However, if I write, `exports.num = 10` in a `.ts` file, I get `error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''./myModule''` and `error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.`  So, is it possible to use the JS syntax since valid JS is supposed to be valid TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described basically exactly how external modules in TypeScript work.

For example:

**Animals.ts**

```
export class Animal {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}

export function somethingElse() { /* etc */ }
```

**Zoo.ts**

```
import a = require('./Animals');
var lion = new a.Animal('Lion'); // Typechecked
console.log(lion.name);
```

Compile with `--module commonjs` and run zoo.js in node.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering is I can use the same syntax as nodejs i.e. assigning properties to the `exports` object. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you compile and run as he said? Because it does EXACTLY what you're asking... just try it.

Comment: You could assign to the `exports` object manually, but that's what the compiler is emitting for you anyway. Using the built-in module system in TypeScript allows you to have type safety when consuming the exported members. Have you looked at the generated code from this example?

Comment: @Jake @Ryan : When I compile that, I get the output I want. However, if I just paste that output in the `.ts` file and compile that, it gives me these errors : `error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''./myModule''` , `error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.`

Comment: For example I can simply do `exports.num = 10` in a node module, however doing that in TS gives errors. So, I was asking if I can just use that syntax in .ts files since any valid Javascript is supposed to be valid TS. Also, I tried `export num = 10` in TS but that doesn't work also.

Comment: `declare var exports;` then do whatever you want.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I added `declare var exports` at the top (and had also included node.d.ts) and I still get those same errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to use the true js syntax. You are receiving the error since you are using the `import` keyword which expects the imported file to use the `export` keyword.  If you want the js `exports.foo` syntax you should use `var` instead of import. The following will compile/work just fine:

```
var module = require('module.ts')
```

Comment: Let's say that I am exporting `module.ts` in `main.ts` then compiling `main.ts` doesn't compile `module.ts`, and it doesn't give any errors if supple different arguments to a function in main.ts which was defined in module.ts. 
Also, the compiled js file contains `require('module.ts')` which, I think, shouldn't be this way.